# How to run the shell command in the appointed line in vim?

Tags: vim

I have a file edited in Vim with many lines. There is a specific line that contains a shell command, which I want to run.
How can I do this through Vim?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Use

```
 :exec '!'.getline('.')
```

This is like to copy the current line and run it.

You can also map this command to

```
 map <F12> :exec '!'.getline('.')
```

getline receives the number of the line. if you will write 4 it will the line 4. The "." it run the current line.

so for run the command in line 4 you can write.

```
:exec '!'.getline(4)
```

Comment: Is there another way to use number 4 to do the same job?

Comment: Ctrl+4 ? you cant map ctrl+number in vim

Comment: The cursor is on the first line ,but i want to make the 4th line to be runned?

Comment: getline receives the number of the line. if you will write 4 it will the line 4. the "." it run the current line.

Comment: if it helps you don't forget to upvote the answerer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this map:

```
:nmap ^ GI:!^V^[yy@"Xx
```

(Pick your favorite key command you don't use in place of `^` for the mapping;I like `^` because I always use `0` for its default function. Enter the `^V^[` with *control-V control-V control-V Esc*)

Then you can type `4^` to execute line 4, or just `^` to execute the last line in the file.